# Хочу, чтобы команда работала только для определенного человека (по id)

Tags: python, telebot, python-telegram-bot

```py
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot('токен моего бота')

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_text_messages(message):
    if message.text == "Привет":
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Привет, чем я могу тебе помочь?")
    elif message.text == "/help":
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Напиши привет")
    elif message.text == "/start":
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Напиши привет")
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Я тебя не понимаю. Напиши /help.")

@bot.message_handler(commands=['info'])
def send_message_user(message):
    if message.from_user.id == 'айди человека':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Hello')
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'error')

bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

Comment: А зачем вы айди пользователя сравниваете с простой строкой "id"?

Comment: А как надо? Я просто от шаблона с интернета написал, а так только айди написал

Comment: Я просто не понял правильно

Comment: Если вообще бот не отвечает, то я не знаю, код правильно написан. Тогда давай ты мне покажешь весь код.

Comment: https://ibb.co/qDxqswZ ссылка на скриншот

Comment: @Mark код добавьте в сам вопрос (текстом, не скриншотом)

Comment: Добавил теперь.

Comment: Я не уверен что бот может работать с кодом запущенным на телефоне.

Comment: Не знаю, у меня  команды выше отлично работают

Answer (score 1):

Если надо чтобы бот отвечал конкретному человеку, то вот:

```py
@bot.message_handler(commands=['info'])
def send_message_user(message):
    if message.from_user.id == id пользователя integer:
      bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Hello')
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'error')
```

Можно через username:

```py
@bot.message_handler(commands=['info'])
def send_message_user(message):
    if message.from_user.username == "Здесь имя пользователя":
      bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Hello')
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'error')
```

Answer (score 1):

у меня это реализовано так:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['stop']) #
def send_message_user(message):
    if message.from_user.id == 1234: #id пользователя
      bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'До свидания, я отключаюсь пока 
Создатель не разбудит меня...') # сообщение если id подходит
      print('Work stoping...') # вывод сообщения в консоль
      bot.stop_polling() # остановка бота
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ты не имеешь на это прав)') # если id не подходит
```

это конкретно для определенной команды.
А это уже ограничение вообще на все сообщения:

```
users = [useInfo.id_users]  # список id пользователей имеющих доступ к боту

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.chat.id not in users[0])
def some(message):
    file = open('./not.jpeg', 'rb')
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, file)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Извините, Создатель не разрешает мне общаться с незнакомыми пользователями.')
```

Answer (score -1):

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['info'])
def send_message_user(message):
    if message.from_user.id == ВАШ ID:
      bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Hello')
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'error'
```

Где, ВАШ ID - это число, которое вы можете найти вот в этом боте: https://t.me/username_to_id_bot